# Spring Boot HTTPS call throws SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have an old application which is required to download a file from a HTTPS url by providing credentials and it throws the following error when a request is done:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
```

Here is the way the client is configured :

```
  final CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    final UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(artifact.getDownloadSource().getHttpUsername(),
            artifact.getDownloadSource().getHttpPassword());
    provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    // use the TrustSelfSignedStrategy to allow Self Signed Certificates
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();

    // create an SSL Socket Factory to use the SSLContext with the trust self signed certificate strategy
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory connectionFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    return HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory)
            .build();
```

An here is the spring boot configurations:

```
server:
port: 8443
http.port: 8080
ssl:
  key-store: src/main/resources/ssl/keystore.p12
  key-store-password: mykeystorepassword
  keyStoreType: PKCS12
  keyAlias: mykeyalias
```

NOTE: the keystore has a certificate that expired 2 years ago.

The application was running without an issue untill this morning. When doing a CURL request and providing the credentials from the command line inside the docker container i am able to download the file without an issue so the problem is in the spring boot application.

Comment: What's java version used?